# Ajax Success Function parameter not defined Error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets, google-visualization

i am trying to get JSON data from servlet to ajax when i print Json data in servlet it is printing data
but in ajax success: function(jsonData) it says that jsonData variable is not defined.
**code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: function () {

        drawChart();
        function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'Get_Sensor',
            type: 'get',
            dataType:"json",
            contentType: "application/json",                
            success: function (jsonData) 
            {
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              data.addColumn('string', 'word');
              data.addColumn('number', 'count');

              alert(" --->  "+jsonData.length);   **Here i am getting Undefined**
              for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
              {
                   data.addRow([jsonData[i].word, jsonData[i].count]);
              }
              var options = {
                      title: 'Word Count',
                      is3D: true
                  };
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data,options);
            }
          });
        }
      },
      packages: ['corechart']
    });
</script>
```

Servlet Code is

```
String[] word = {"a","b","c","d","f","g"};
    int[] count1 = {20,4,12,30,56,1};
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        for(int i =0; i<word.length; i++) 
        {
            json.put(word[i], count1[i]);
        }
    } 
    catch (JSONException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Gson().toJson(json, response.getWriter());
```

Any suggestion will appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for that, now I corrected it but in for loop i spelled it correct only it is not entering into for loop that's way i wrote alert, even though i am getting same error..

Comment: please replace the alert with, and share the result of --> `alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));`